# Vuejs how to use method in include component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, vue-component

In Vuejs I have created a new component for a form and added this new component to the existing index component. In this new component, I want to validate few fields. The methods related to that validation I have already created in the parent component. Now I want to use these functions in the child components. I have googled it and checked a few solutions but it's not working for me.

**parent component:**

```html
<div v-if="operation.operationName=='addUser'">
  <add-user-form
    :module="module"
    :operation="operation"
  >
  </add-user-form>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to research [Vue Mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your child component `add-user-form` you can use a [custom event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) when user submits or edits a field.

I'm not sure how your child component looks like but you can do something like this:

child component

```
<label>
  Username:
  <input
    v-on:input="$emit('usernameChanged', $event.target.value)"
  >
</label>
```

parent component

```
<div v-if="operation.operationName=='addUser'">
  <add-user-form
    :module="module"
    :operation="operation"
    v-on:usernameChanged="validateUsername"
  >
  </add-user-form>
</div>
```

and add a method validateUsername

```
methods:{
  validateUsername(value){
    //validate username
  }
}
```